# Change duration/speed of Leaflet moving marker during animation dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, markers

I am using leaflet moving marker functionality. I have defined duration when define marker.

```
this.marker = L.Marker.movingMarker(this.locations,
        this.duration, {autostart: false}).addTo(this.map);
```

Now i want to change duration/speed of moving marker on button click event.
For example first the duration was **2000** now i want to change it to **1000** dynamically.
How can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
function changeDuration(marker, duration){
    marker.pause();
    marker._currentDuration = duration;
    marker.start();
}
```

Comment: How do I call this function?